# Workaround on return type covariance on C# properties

Tags: c#

I need an advice on how to solve this.

We have a component that displays charts and uses a definition to do so:

```
public interface IChartDefinition
{
    IAxisDefinition AxisDefinition { get; }
}

public interface IAxisDefinition
{
}
```

This is in separate project.

And in our application we created a concrete implementation:

```
class CustomChartDefinition : IChartDefinition
{
    public IAxisDefinition AxisDefinition { get; }
}

class CustomAxisDefinition : IAxisDefinition
{
    private Descriptor DataDescriptor { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the extra *Descriptor* property on *CustomAxisDefinition*.

From the components position, everything is fine as it should be.

But consider we need a custom behavior that uses *CustomChartDefinition* as input and need to access *DataDescriptor*. It cannot be accessed directly because *CustomChartDefinition* contains *IAxisDefinition* instead of *CustomAxisDefinition*. This wouldn't be a problem if C# supported return type covariance, sadly it doesn't.

Apart from casting I have found several solution on StackOverflow, but each of them have several drawbacks:

1. Using generics. It looks like a nice solution, but will soon result in generic definition being very long. In my example I would need to replace *IChartDefinition* with *IChartDefinition<IAxisDefinion>*. That would be problem, but *IAxisDefinion* may contain properties that need to solve the same issue, which can soon turn into something like *IChartDefinition<IAxisDefinition<IOther<Something>>>*. And this is how any field for chart definition would have to be defined.
2. Using second property with the specific type, but this duplicates code.
3. Using **new** keyword on derived class, but it is almost as 2 and has the same drawbacks.

Because return type covariance was suggested as C# feature a long time ago, yet hasn't been implemented, I figure there must be a nicer solution I haven't found.

Or maybe there is an inherent flaw in my design of *IChartDefinition*.

Thanks for any advice how to approach this problem.

Comment: You know better than the compiler that a `CustomChartDefinition` will only ever return `CustomAxisDefinition` objects from the `AxisDefinition` property - seems an ideal use case for a cast. What's the problem with doing that?

Comment: I know it now, but it doesn't mean other developer or me in six months will know that. What if somebody create a derived type of CustomChartDefinition that uses something else than CustomAxisDefinition. I get InvalidCastException. And on top of that this makes it much harder to mock for unit testing.

Comment: Fact: C# won't allow you to override the return type. Fact: this means you will have to write the return type you're actually after at least one more time, even though this appears redundant. Conclusion: rejecting approaches because they "duplicate code" isn't sensible; no matter what you do, there will have to be another line of code somewhere that mentions your return type and accesses the other property, whether it's a `new` member, another property, a method call (`GetAxisDefinition<T>() where T : IAxisDefinition`), or what have you.